# Enlive - Wrap tags around HTML from file

Tags: clojure, enlive

So I have the following HTML in `logout.html`:

```
<form id="log_out" name="log_out" action="/log_out" method="post">
  <input type="submit"
         value="Log Out!">
  </input>
</form>
```

It looks like I need some function to read `logout.html` as enlive nodes (At least I think `wrap` takes nodes; I'm not actually sure).

```
(html/defsnippet nav "templates/nav.html" [:ul]
      []
      [:ul] (html/append
                  (html/wrap :li (html/SOME-FUNCTION-IDK "templates/logout.html"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to modify overthink's answer to get it working.

```
(defn extract-body
  "Enlive uses TagSoup to parse HTML. Because it assumes that it's dealing with
   something potentially toxic, and tries to detoxify it, it adds <head> and
   <body> tags around any HTML you give it. So the DOM returned by html-resource
   has these extra tags which end up wrapping the content in the middle of our
   webpage. We need to strip these extra tags out."
  [html]
  (html/at html [#{:html :body}] html/unwrap))

(html/defsnippet logout "templates/logout.html" [html/root] [])
```

How `wrap` works is it wraps selected elements in a given tag. So in this case, `#log_out` is selected and is wrapped with the `li` tag.

```
(html/defsnippet nav "templates/nav.html" [html/root]
      []
      [:ul] (html/append (extract-body (logout)))
      [:#log_out] (html/wrap :li))
```

It's definitely not as clean as I'd like, but it works.

Comment: You might be able to avoid the extract-body hack by changing your defsnippet like so: `(html/defsnippet logout "templates/logout.html" [:#log_out] [])`.  i.e. select the form by id out of the logout.html file.

Comment: Yep, looks like that avoids the `extract-body` hack.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could define the contents of `logout.html` as an enlive snippet.  A snippet is like a template, but returns nodes, and can also selectively grab parts of the file given a selector (in the example below, the selector is `:#log_out`, meaning the form element with id="log_out").

```
(html/defsnippet logout-form "templates/logout.html" [:#log_out] 
  [])
```

Then something like:

```
(html/defsnippet nav "templates/nav.html" [:ul]
  []
  [:ul] (html/append
          ((html/wrap :li) (logout-form))))) ;; untested! ymmv
```